# How to create a data frame from several named vectors

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following string and vectors variable:

```
x <- "FOO"
y <- c(A = 0.25, R = 0, N = 0)
z <- c(KA = 0.33, KK = 0.33, AW = 0.33)
```

What I want to create is a data frame with `x` as row names and  values of `y` & `z`
as column name. Yielding in something that looks like:

```
       A      R     N   KA    KK    AW
FOO   0.25    0     0   0.33  0.33  0.33
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

```
data.frame(as.list(c(y, z)), row.names = x)
#        A R N   KA   KK   AW
# FOO 0.25 0 0 0.33 0.33 0.33
```